# How to check if login user belongs to domain admin group in active directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

How to check if login user belongs to domain admin group in active directory?
If yes I want to show a control. 
Any ideas pls..

Comment: Check this out, it might help.  Also consider expanding your question a bit. http://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a MembershipUser you could just check using Roles.IsUserInRole("Rolename")

Comment: Thankyou all, just came to know first we need to create this group in AD